# Child component constructor called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-props

I have a parent component which is a flat list which contains a header `HeaderComponent`. This `HeaderComponent` is a custom component that I have created which contains 2 child components of its own. Whenever i refresh the list, I am passing a boolean to the `HeaderComponent` as props which get passed onto its own children, I am doing this so I can check if each component needs to fetch new data or not. The problem is that whenever the parent refreshes and sets a new state the constructors of the child components get called everytime. Shouldn't the constructor be called only the first time the parent initializes and then all further calls involve calling the shouldComponentUpdate method of the children in order to see if it needs an update or not.

Parent component

```
_renderHeader = () => {
    return <HeaderComponent Items={this.state.Data} refresh={this.state.refresh}/>;
};

render() {
    console.log("TAG_RENDER render called " + this.state.refresh);
    return (
        <FlatList
            refreshing={this.state.refresh}
            onRefresh={() => {
                console.log("onRefresh");
                this.setState({
                    refresh: true
                }, () => {
                    this._fetchData();
                });
            }}
            ......


            ListHeaderComponent={() => this._renderHeader()}
            .......
        />
    );
}
```

Header Component

```
export default class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.debug("HeaderComponent");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MainHeader Items={this.props.Items}/>
            <SubHeader refresh={this.props.refresh}/>
        );
    }

}
```

The constructor of `MainHeader` and `Subheader` gets called whenever the parent component refreshes. Does this mean that it is creating new child components each time it refreshes because I can see the render of the children also being called multiple times.

Comment: What about `constructor` of `HeaderComponent`? Is it also getting called multiple times?

Comment: It does, I also noticed that replaceing `ListHeaderComponent={() => this._renderHeader()}` with `ListHeaderComponent={this._renderHeader()}` prevents that and gives me the behaviour that I am looking for, does this mean that the anonymous function is creating new instances of the `HeaderComponent` every single time which is why react detects it as a new component and never checks the existing one?

Comment: React guides say that using anonymous functions can have a side effect where child component renders unnecessary even if the child components dont change.

Comment: @G_S so is it a good idea to replace all my anonymous functions with instance functions as in the default way of declaring a function and use them, not just for this but also for network calls and set state calls?

Comment: Yes. as per react docs, need to use either bind() or class property syntax.

Comment: @G_S could you give me a link to the pages in the docs i need to refer to.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html check this

Answer (score 20):

Control your `index.js` file. If you see `<React.StrictMode>`, you should change to `<>`. This is solved my problem.

It should be like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <App/>
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Why does `<React.StrictMode>` cause this?

Comment: @Nathan Refer this link - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-613145789

Answer (score 8):

As correctly stated in the one of the answers , removing the strict mode fixes the issue. Coming to why it does that, its because the strict mode intentionally calls the 'render' method twice in order to detect potential problems.

React works in two phases:render and commit. Render phase checks and determines the new changes to be applied. And commit phase applies it.

Render phase lifecycle includes methods like : constructor, UNSAFE_componentWillMount,UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps, ...,render and few more.

The render phase is time consuming and is often broken into pieces to free up the browser. Render phase might be called multiple times before the commit phase(usually very fast).
Since the render phase methods are called more than once, its important that none of those method have any problems or side effects.

Thus just in order to highlight the possible side effects to make them easy to spot, react explicitly double invoke the render phase methods.

You can read more about this on :https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects :)

Answer (score 3):

Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

- Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate
  methods
- Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
- Function component bodies
- State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
- Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

As stated in the site,
Note:
This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be double-invoked in production mode.