# react.js constructor called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I a have post list and I am trying to call an action inside of constructor or componentDidMount for each post. But somehow when I send a new message constructor and componentDidMount functions are called twice.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    if (condition1) {
       this.props.actions.action1();
    } else if (condition2) {
       this.props.actions.action2();
    }    
}
```

These functions are called only once when the posts are readed from a list. But when I send a new message they are called twice.

How can i avoid these situation. I tried to use componendDidUpdate function like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {     
      if (prevProps.post.id !== this.props.post.id) {
         if (condition1) {
            this.props.actions.action1();
         } else if (condition2) {
            this.props.actions.action2();
         }
      }   
}
```

Comment: Weird, make sure you're not using the component twice?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. When send an message I don't see more than one component

Comment: same problem for mine. How did you get solutions @burakunlu

Answer (score 29):

React constructor is called twice in strict mode.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61443443/6014725

This is not a bug, but on purpose behavior to ensure that the constructor is pure.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-613145789

Learn more with https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: This is a great answer. That was a poor design choice.

Answer (score 2):

Well, when your constructor and your componentDidMount function both fire twice you can be sure that the component in question is constructed twice somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not running StrictMode (if you are, see answer by papacool: it's by design), when the code in the constructor is run twice, you can be sure that the component is being created anew two times. This can happen of various reasons, the simplest reason is probably that the component is being used on multiple places:

```
<MyComponent />
<MyComponent />
```

Another reason could be that you have conditional rendering, meaning perhaps you're rendering based on a boolean, that changes:

```
{ myBoolean && <MyComponent /> }
```

If you toggle myBoolean two times, the constructor will be executed two times.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this

```js
let onlyonce = false;

class PostPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.struct()
    }
    async struct() {
        if(onlyonce) return;
        onlyonce = true;
//dom loading
    }
}
```