# Why console.log in react runs twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

Everytime I run my code on reactjs, console.log() runs twice in constructor,render, or in the components. Why does it do that?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log("[App.js] constructor")
  }
```

Comment: does it answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using React in Strict Mode. Hence it occurs twice. This wont happen when you use production build of your react app.
[This might help you further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119377/react-js-constructor-called-twice)